# Is there a win_npm or equivalent module in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am looking for a npm module that works on windows computers, is there something out there?

If not, what are some alternatives?

I know of win_command, which can then run npm, however, I am looking for something that is idempotent by ansible

Comment: I don't use windows much so I might be totally wrong and my question might seem totally dumb. But I don't see anything on the module [documentation page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/npm_module.html) nor in the [source code](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/packaging/language/npm.py) making it incompatible with windows targets. The only listed requirement is to have the `npm` command in your target machine path. Did you actually try the module before looking for an other one ?

Comment: @Zeitounator I did and I kept on recieving an error that python was not installed on my system even though it was. I wrote it off as python being natively installed on linux (I believe I am correct on that), so the module was looking in the wrong place for python. I think it was looking at :/cmd/python but /cmd is not a native folder in windows. The machine is not even supposed to have python installed so I did not dig deeper than that





Edit: Sorry, the path is usr/python, however, there is no usr folder in windows

Comment: Ok my bad, `npm` module is a python module and is hence not supported when running on windows: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_faq.html#can-i-run-python-modules-on-windows-hosts. I have no idea of what to replace it with. Meanwhile, it would work if you connect to your windows box via a WSL environment (in which case you basically act as a linux box).